# Problema con Mysql no quiere iniciar

Tags: php, mysql

Este problema me anduvo persiguiendo por varios meses, con la única solución de volver a instalar el xampp nuevamente (cosa que no es recomendable si tu proyecto, juego e etc... tiene una base de datos grande porque se perderá todo).

El problema aparece repentinamente, es decir, no sé si sea al cambiar datos del phpmyadmin (cuentas de usuario) o otro problema interno. ¿Alguna solución?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que cambios hiciste antes que empezar esto? que dice el visor de eventos de windows?

Comment: Sólo borre todas las cuentas de usuario 'root' y cree una propia con clave y con cualquier servidor (%)

Comment: borraste todas las cuentas de usuario root? y no pensas que tal vez alguna de ellas las usaba mysql para hacer procesos internos?

Comment: Eso no lo pensé, pensaba que todas las cuentas root era pues para acceso al phpmyadmin.

Comment: Desconozco.. pero si no es la primera vez que te pasa.. y antes hiciste lo mismo, ya descubriste el problema :)

Comment: Me pasó solo 2 veces, entonces ese sería el problema. Tendrías que volver a instalar mysql. Pero haré otro post hablando sobre éste tema para aquéllos que no estén informados no les pase lo mismo.

Comment: No hagas otro post.. Comenta exactamente que hiciste. volve a replicar el error. Pone cual seria la solucion. En este caso no es un error, mas bien rompiste el sistema. Salvo, que lo que hayas hecho tenga solucion...

Comment: Dudo que tenga solución, ya que no me deja ingresar para volver a colocar las cuentas de usuario. La solución sería reinistalar el xampp pero sin borrar las cuentas de usuario 'root', si te sientes vulnerable ante esto simplemente quítale los permisos.

Comment: Porque hablas de cuentas de usuario root (en plural) deberias tener un solo usuario root, y no usarlo nunca...

Comment: Es que, en las últimas versiones de xampp aparentemente hay más de 1 sola cuenta root, entonces de allí viene la confusión de borrar cuentas root.

Comment: xampp es una maquina virtual autocontenido.. que sentido tiene romper una maquina que solo sirve para si misma?

Comment: No soy experto en esto de xampp, ni conozco hasta ahora lo de 'romper el sistema' de Mysql borrando dichas cuentas de root, pero entonces ya aprendí sobre el error de borrarlas.